# Lambda copy assignment operator is not defined

Tags: c++, clang, c++17

Why this does not compile with CLang 7 and lower, but compiles with CLang 8 and above:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

typedef std::map<std::string, int> TestMap;

TestMap m {
    {"a", 1},
    {"b", 2},
    {"c", 3},
};

auto func = [](const TestMap::value_type & p) -> int { return p.second; };
auto func1 = func;
//In CLang 7 and lower copy assignment operator is not defined
func = func1;
```

what actually changed?

But this compiles with all CLang versions:

```
auto func1 = []() { return 5;};
decltype(func1) func2 = func1;
func2 = func1;
```

All the sample code available [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sth5JwOMeEgIW6jM)

what is the difference between lambdas?

Comment: Nice question. You probably want to wrap your code in a function, in order to make it easier for other people to reproduce your results (`func2 = func1` is not a valid expression in the global scope)

Comment: @CássioRenan see https://wandbox.org/permlink/sth5JwOMeEgIW6jM

Comment: Stateless lambdas can be copied since C++20 [see reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). Now enter [clang status](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) and check status of *c++2a*. Clang in 8 version supports assignable stateless lambdas. Look for this *Default constructible and assignable stateless lambdas* paper. You attached link the code where *c++2a* mode is enabled.

Comment: doesn't compile with clang 8 either. https://godbolt.org/z/r5csI3

Comment: @user10933809 You need to add `-std=c++2a` as compiler parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @rafix07 mentioned in the comments, you have to compile with C++20 standard.

the standard prior to C++20:

```
ClosureType& operator=(const ClosureType&) = delete; (until C++20)
```

> If no captures are specified, the closure type has a defaulted copy
>   assignment operator and a defaulted move assignment
>   operator. Otherwise, it has a deleted copy assignment operator (this
>   includes the case when there is a capture-default, even if it does not
>   actually capture anything). (since C++20)
>
> The copy assignment operator is defined as deleted (and the move
>   assignment operator is not declared). Closure types are not
>   CopyAssignable. (until C++20)
>       ClosureType::operator=(const ClosureType&)
>
> ```
> ClosureType& operator=(const ClosureType&) = delete; (until C++20)
>
> ClosureType& operator=(const ClosureType&) = default; (since C++20) 
> ClosureType& operator=(ClosureType&&) = default; (only if no captures are specified)
>
> ClosureType& operator=(const ClosureType&) = delete; (since C++20) 
> (otherwise)
> ```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

see the compilation here: https://godbolt.org/z/jpCYNQ

code sample taken from @Alexey Starinsky link in the comments.